# How to using Zimbra LDAP authentication to svn

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm using Zimbra mail with LDAP extension. Now, I want to use Zimbra mail authentication accept to SVN (web server Apache).

eg: config SVN in web server for me:

```
AuthLDAPURL ldap://mail.my-domain:389/ou=people,dc=my-domain,dc=com?mail?sub?(objectClass=organizationalPerson)
```

Next, I'm want to create a new group in Zimbra LDAP (eg: svngroup) and accept with link:

```
AuthLDAPURL ldap://mail.my-domain:389/ou=svngroup,dc=my-domain,dc=com?mail?sub?(objectClass=organizationalPerson)
```

I'm trying but get the error "password mismatch: /svn".

Help me create new group in Zimbra LDAP and accept to link with "OU" group news?